# Is it possible to call async Page_Load in asp.net 4.5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-4.5

I wish to know whether it possible to call async Page_Load in asp.net 4.5 like async controllers in ASP.Net MVC 4. If it is possible, how do we use async events in asp.net?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [PageAsyncTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pageasynctask.aspx)

Pretty simple to use. You basically create your async task and then register it with the page and execute it. The link above has a good example.