# Running Async tasks on asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, webforms

I am connnecting to an API and using an Async library (Koenzomers) when I run this from a console app, it works absolutely fine, when I run it from a asp.net webform page I can't get it to work.

Code I have

if I try to run the task as I run from the console app

```
                    Task TestAuth = TestOtherLibrary();
                    TestAuth.Wait();
```

I get the same result.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Authenticating");
    RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(Auth));
}

public async Task Auth()
{
    using (KoenZomers.UniFi.Api.Api UnifiApp = new KoenZomers.UniFi.Api.Api(new System.Uri("https://myserverurl"), "unifisiteid"))
    {
    await UnifiApp.Authenticate("admin", "mysecurepassword");

    }
}
```

The idea is to connect to the unifi controller and authorize user based on mac address

Currently, I get the page loading in a deadlock, not sure if the UI is waiting for the task to end, and it never ends.

Comment: Have you [set `httpRuntime.targetFramework`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/)?

Comment: Duplicate question with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47341289/asp-net-call-an-async-method-in-page-load ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using PageAsyncTask, Use the below one,

`var localVariable = Task.Run(async () => await Auth())?.Result;`